# Number of inscribed $4$-simplices in a $600$-cell

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, symmetry, simplex, polytopes

The title says it all, I'm wondering what number of different (not necessarily regular) $4$-simplices can be inscribed into a [$600$-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/600-cell) modulo the full symmetry group of the latter (the vertices of each $4$-simplex should be among the vertices of the $600$-cell). Degenerate $4$-simplices (i.e. those lying in a single hyperplane) don't count.

I would probably try to approach this using [the lemma which is not Burnside's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma). I originally used it to count the number of triangles in an $n$-gon up to rotations and reflections, which comes out to $\big[\frac{n^2}{12}\big]$, and the number of tetrahedra in an icosahedron up to rotations ($10$) and up to rotations plus reflections ($8$) (I think at least; the icosahedron is pretty nasty to look at). The problem with this approach is that it requires some visual intuition about the geometry and this is doesn't really work in $4D$. I have no idea how to even begin.